# How do I efficiently bin values into overlapping bins using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, binning

I would like to bin all the values from a column of type float into bins that are overlapping. The resulting column could be a series of 1-D vectors with bools - one vector for each value from the original column. The resulting vectors contain `True` for each bin a value falls into and `False` for the other bins.

For example, if I have four bins `[(0, 10), (7, 20), (15, 30), (30, 60)]`, and the original value is 9.5, the resulting vector should be `[True, True, False, False]`.

I know how to iterate through all the ranges with a custom function using 'apply', but is there a way to perform this binning more efficiently and concisely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would a simple list comprehension meet your needs?

```
Bins = [(0, 10), (7, 20), (15, 30), (30, 60)]
Result = [((9.5>=y[0])&(9.5<=y[1])) for y in Bins]
```

If your data is stored in column `data` of a pandas DataFrame (`df`) then you can define the function:

```
def in_ranges(x,bins):
    return [((x>=y[0])&(x<=y[1])) for y in bins]
```

and apply it to the column:

```
df[data].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(in_ranges(x,Bins),Bins))
```