# In Pandas, how do I bin floats and count string types from other cols where the bin is of a rolling, overlapping numeric range of constant size?

Tags: pandas, overlapping, binning

I have a table of float values and strings such as the following:

| FltVal | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 0.01 | A |
| 0.02 | A |
| 0.05 | B |
| 0.31 | B |
| 0.36 | A |
| 0.37 | C |
| 0.41 | B |

I would like to produce a new dataframe that bins the float values into bins of size 0.3 (so each bin is (x, x + 0.3]) and that overlaps in 0.01 increments. Additionally I'd like a column tallying the number of records following into the bin, as well as a column tallying each 'Category' total for the bin.

I first tried to get a basic count going with groupby and pd.cut (before trying to find counts for each Category):

```
import pandas as pd

floats = pd.Series([0.01,0.02,0.05,0.31,0.36,0.37,0.41])
categories = pd.Series(['A','A','B','B','A','C','B'])
data = {"FltVal": floats, "Category": categories}
df = pd.concat(data, axis=1)

grouped_vals = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['FltVal'],np.arange(df['FltVal'].min(),df['FltVal'].max(),0.3))).count()
```

Output:

```
FltVal  Category
FltVal  
(0.01, 0.31]       3         3
```

I think the problem there was that it couldn't consider another bin, let alone overlapping?

Then, with the idea I could just throw out non-sensible (like negatives) ranges afterward, I tried the following:

```
FltVal_range = np.arange(df['FltVal'].min(),df['FltVal'].max(),0.01)
FltVal_range_from = FltVal_range - 0.3
FltVal_range_to = FltVal_range
FltVal_intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(FltVal_range_from,FltVal_range_to)
binned_df = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['FltVal'], FltVal_intervals))
```

But got the ValueError message:

`Overlapping IntervalIndex is not accepted.`

If pd.cut doesn't accept overlapping bins, I guess it's a non-starter.

Regardless, desired output is the following:

| FloatBin | Count | Cat_A | Cat_B | Cat_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.00, 0.30 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 0.01, 0.31 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 0.02, 0.32 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 0.03, 0.33 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 0.04, 0.34 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 0.05, 0.35 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0.06, 0.36 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0.07, 0.37 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0.08, 0.38 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0.09, 0.39 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0.1, 0.4 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0.11, 0.41 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

An efficient approach is necessary as the actual dataframe will have rows in the hundreds-of-thousands to millions.

I'm thinking of something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44005652/how-do-i-efficiently-bin-values-into-overlapping-bins-using-pandas) but suitable for finding counts for all my categories.

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: how big is your data set?

Comment: Original dataset is about 10,000 rows, taking into account maybe 20 categories, but I'd also like this process to work for other datasets in the range of 100k to ~1M rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option using `janitor`'s [`conditional_join`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join):

```
import janitor

FltVal_range = np.arange(df['FltVal'].min(), df['FltVal'].max(), 0.01)

tmp = (pd.crosstab(df['FltVal'], df['Category'],
                   margins=True, margins_name='Count')
         .drop('Count')
       )

out = (pd.DataFrame({'low': FltVal_range, 'high': FltVal_range+0.3})
         .conditional_join(tmp.reset_index(),
                           ('low', 'FltVal', '<'),
                           ('high', 'FltVal', '>='))
         .groupby(['low', 'high'])[list(tmp)].sum()
      )
```

Output:

```
           A  B  C  Count
low  high                
0.01 0.31  1  2  0      3
0.02 0.32  0  2  0      2
0.03 0.33  0  2  0      2
0.04 0.34  0  2  0      2
0.05 0.35  0  1  0      1
0.06 0.36  1  1  0      2
0.07 0.37  1  1  1      3
0.08 0.38  1  1  1      3
0.09 0.39  1  1  1      3
0.10 0.40  1  1  1      3
0.11 0.41  1  2  1      4
0.12 0.42  1  2  1      4
0.13 0.43  1  2  1      4
0.14 0.44  1  2  1      4
0.15 0.45  1  2  1      4
...
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!

Also curious for anyone else out there if you had a solution with no other dependencies.

Comment: @chroberts I don't think there is a pure pandas way that would be as efficient. Unfortunately, pandas has no builtin many-to-many merge function based on non-exact matches.